# boolean and arithmetic expression grammar in ANTLR

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I'm trying to write a grammar for arithmetic and boolean expressions. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. For my grammar, ANTLR says:

> [fatal] rule logic_atom has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

But I can't do a left-factoring. And I don't want to touch `arith_expr`, because for this I have a code.

Error in `logic_atom :   LBR logic_expr  RBR |  cmp_expr  ;`

My code:

```
grammar ArithmeticInterpreter;

options { 
    output = AST;
    language = C;
}
//options{greedy=true;}:

axiom : lines EOF! ;
lines : line (SEP! line)* ;
line  : (def_var | print_expr | scan_expr)? ;

def_var    : VARIABLE ASSIGMENT^ logic_expr ;
print_expr : PRINT_KEYW^ arith_expr ;
scan_expr  : SCAN_KEYW^ VARIABLE ;

arith_expr : ((PLS | MNS)^)? term ((PLS | MNS)^ term)*;
term       : power ((MLP | DIV)^ power )*;
power      : atom  (options{greedy=true;}: PWR^ power )*;
atom       : INT | FLOAT | VARIABLE | LBR arith_expr RBR -> ^(arith_expr);

logic_expr    : logic_atom ((OR | AND)^ logic_atom)*;
logic_atom :   LBR logic_expr  RBR |  cmp_expr  ;
cmp_expr: arith_expr (LSS | LSQ | GRT | GRQ | EQL | NEQ) arith_expr;

WS  : ( ' '| '\t'| '\r') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

LBR :  '(' ;
RBR :  ')' ;
PLS :  '+' ;
MNS :  '-' ;
MLP :  '*' ;
DIV :  '/' ;
PWR :  '^' ;

LSS :  '<'  ;
LSQ :  '<=' ;
GRT :  '>'  ;
GRQ :  '>=' ;
EQL :  '==' ;
NEQ :  '!=' ;
AND :  '&&' ;
OR  :  '||' ;
NOT :  '!'  ;

ASSIGMENT : '=' ;
PRINT_KEYW : 'print' ;
SCAN_KEYW  : 'scan' ;

SEP : '\n' | ';' ;

INT :  ('0'..'9')+;

FLOAT : INT '.' INT* EXP? | '.' INT EXP? | INT EXP;
fragment EXP : ('e'|'E') (PLS | MNS)? INT;

VARIABLE : SS (SS | '0'..'9')* ;
fragment SS : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' ;
```

// `(LBR arith_expr)=>` isn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider changing your `logic_expr` and `cmp_expr` to this:

```
logic_expr : cmp_expr ((OR | AND)^ cmp_expr)*;
cmp_expr   : (arith_expr (LSS | LSQ | GRT | GRQ | EQL | NEQ))=> arith_expr (LSS | LSQ | GRT | GRQ | EQL | NEQ)^ arith_expr
           | LBR logic_expr RBR -> logic_expr
           ;
```

I removed the rule `logic_atom` because it obscures the error that you're getting and doesn't add value.

By using the syntactic predicate in `cmp_expr`, you're able to tell ANTLR that any `arith_expr` followed by a logic sign will only be followed by an `arith_expr`, which means that any parentheses that ANTLR encounters must belong to an arithmetic expression and not a logical one.

This ensures that `logic_expr` only deals with boolean values and `arith_expr` only deals with numeric values.

---

I tested various scenarios with the modified grammar and I'm not getting errors in ANTLRWorks or in my custom test code. Could you post more information about what you're seeing?

Here is the full grammar I'm using. Note that I removed the `language` so that I could test this in Java. This should be fine since there are no actions/semantic predicates. I also made a few small changes, but I don't expect them to be serious fixes. They're denoted with comments.

```
grammar ArithmeticInterpreter;

options { 
    output = AST;
}
//options{greedy=true;}:

axiom : lines EOF! ;
lines : line (SEP! line)* ;
line  : (def_var | print_expr | scan_expr)? ;

def_var    : VARIABLE ASSIGMENT^ logic_expr ;
print_expr : PRINT_KEYW^ arith_expr ;
scan_expr  : SCAN_KEYW^ VARIABLE ;

arith_expr : ((PLS | MNS)^)? term ((PLS | MNS)^ term)*;
term       : power ((MLP | DIV)^ power )*;
power      : atom  (PWR^ atom)*;  //<-- changed
atom       : INT | FLOAT | VARIABLE 
           | LBR arith_expr RBR -> arith_expr //<-- changed
           ;

logic_expr : cmp_expr ((OR | AND)^ cmp_expr)*;
cmp_expr   : (arith_expr (LSS | LSQ | GRT | GRQ | EQL | NEQ))=> arith_expr (LSS | LSQ | GRT | GRQ | EQL | NEQ)^ arith_expr
           | LBR logic_expr RBR -> logic_expr
           ;

WS  : ( ' '| '\t'| '\r') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

LBR :  '(' ;
RBR :  ')' ;
PLS :  '+' ;
MNS :  '-' ;
MLP :  '*' ;
DIV :  '/' ;
PWR :  '^' ;

LSS :  '<'  ;
LSQ :  '<=' ;
GRT :  '>'  ;
GRQ :  '>=' ;
EQL :  '==' ;
NEQ :  '!=' ;
AND :  '&&' ;
OR  :  '||' ;
NOT :  '!'  ;

ASSIGMENT : '=' ;
PRINT_KEYW : 'print' ;
SCAN_KEYW  : 'scan' ;

SEP : '\n' | ';' ;

INT :  ('0'..'9')+;

FLOAT : INT '.' INT* EXP? | '.' INT EXP? | INT EXP;
fragment EXP : ('e'|'E') (PLS | MNS)? INT;

VARIABLE : SS (SS | '0'..'9')* ;
fragment SS : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' ;
```

---

Given input `x=(2<3)`, the following AST tree is produced:

```
(= x (< 2 3))
```

Which renders like so:

[image: (= x (< 2 3))]

The modified grammar can also handle more complex cases now, like `x = 2 + 3 < 4 || (5 ^ 5 > 30 && 3 == 10 + 2)`:

```
(= x (|| (< (+ 2 3) 4) (&& (> (^ 5 5) 30) (== 3 (+ 10 2)))))
```

[image: a more complex graph]

So try copying the grammar above and seeing if that fixes the error you get. If not, let me know more about the error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm tryed this too. For this antlrworks drawed a bug tree. For example: `x=(1<2)` drawed a `(... -> cmp_expr -> NoViableAltExpression)`

Comment: @AlexanderLavrukov I updated the answer with the grammar I used for testing and some example output. When you get time, try running this grammar yourself to see if it gives you errors.

Comment: @AlexanderLavrukov, make sure you're **not** using the interpreter while testing. Use the debugger instead.

Answer (score 1):

My quick suggestion is to combine arith and logical expressions. See any sample grammar such as Java.g or whatever.  ANTLR v4 would handle this no problem, btw.