# How do I get (A*B)>C string parsed by this grammar?

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

Issue is because of -- addExpression ((EQ | NE | GT | LT | LE | GE) addExpression)+ --- .
By doing this I want to filter the math expressions from being alone unless followed by a relational to make it logical as a whole... I don't want my parser to parse math expressions if alone...

```
expression
    :
        logicalExpression
    ;

primitive
    :
        DECIMAL
    |   UNSIGNED_INTEGER
    |   SIGNED_INTEGER
    |   VARIABLE
    |   '(' logicalExpression ')'
    |   '{' logicalExpression '}'
    |   '[' logicalExpression ']'
    ;

notExpression
    :
        (NOT)* primitive
    ;

signExpression
    :
        ( '-' | '+' )* notExpression
    ;

mulExpression
    :
        signExpression ( ( '*' | '/' ) signExpression)*
    ;

addExpression
    :
        mulExpression ( ( '+' | '-' ) mulExpression)*
    ;

relationalExpression
    :
        addExpression ((EQ | NE | GT | LT | LE | GE) addExpression)+
    |   '(' VARIABLE ')'
    |   '{' VARIABLE '}'
    |   '[' VARIABLE ']'
    |       VARIABLE
    ;
```

Tests:

```
Input string: (5) --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: 5*6 --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: A-B --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: A/B --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: 5/A --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: --2 --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: 5++ --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: A-B and B-A --> Expected: to fail -- Current:failed
    Input string: (A and B)--> Expected: to pass {AND(A,B)} -- Current:failed
    Input string: A and B-->   Expected: to pass AND(A,B) -- Current:failed
    Input string: (5)>6 --> Expected: to pass {GT(5,6)} -- Current:failed
    Input string:  5>6 --> Expected: to pass  {GT(5,6)} -- Current:pass
    Input string: 5*6 < 6-5 --> Expected: to pass  GT(MUL(5,6),SUB(5,6)) --Current:pass
    Input string: A/B == B/A --> Expected: to pass  -- Current:pass
    Input string: (A/B)=B/A --> Expected: to pass  -- Current:failed
    Input string: 5 /= 5 --> Expected: to pass  -- Current:pass
```

Comment: I don't understand. What gets accepted if you do `addExpression ((EQ | NE | GT | LT | LE | GE) addExpression)*` (instead of `addExpression ((EQ | NE | GT | LT | LE | GE) addExpression)+`) that you *don't* want to accept?

Comment: (5*6) or 5*6 gets accepted which I don't want as it is a mathematical expression alone. I only want 5*6>10  or (5*6)>10 to get accepted as it yields logical output even though it has math expressions in it. using '*' makes 5*6 valid where as using '+' will invalidate it as it doesn't have a relational operator which makes my output Boolean I have updated few test to give you better understanding of what I am looking for...

Comment: Wouldn't it be (far) easier to allow for any kind of expression, and just inspect the evaluated value at the end? If it evaluates to a boolean, it's okay, otherwise, reject it.

Comment: I think the grammar in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867525/boolean-and-arithmetic-exression-grammar-in-antlr) does essentially what you're looking for, but it's likely that you'll run into the problem that he did, namely, the difficulty in keeping the expression types (boolean vs. numeric) organized and segregated in the grammar.

Comment: @Bart: I had few more constraints that I need to apply on the end expression as well to evaluate if the variables used in math expressions are mathematical and variables used in logical are boolean... and I have a specific class object(whose parent is an interface for constructing my own AST) that I will be returning [returns $node] {Node node = new Node(OperatorType);} in the return clause. So can you please suggest me a way to isolate the conditions I had?

Comment: @tenterhook: can you please suggest me a way to have my grammar working. Its okey if the solution is a bit complex as I have to get this functionality for sure no matter how hard it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two simple ANTLR grammars that demonstrate two ways to evaluate a mix of logical and arithmetic expressions, followed by a test class and its output. The first grammar is in the form you requested, using ANTLR to determine the expression type and to ensure that expression values are compatible. The other form determines the expression type using actions within the grammar. I'm providing it here for comparison.

I hard-coded expression evaluation in both grammars to make the examples more useful and to show that they work as expected. Please note that I haven't tested these grammars beyond what you see in the test code below. Also, I only included the operators necessary to demonstrate the concepts of interest. It should be easy enough to add others.

---

Asking ANTLR to keep the expression types distinct requires telling ANTLR what to do when an operator is valid for more than one expression type. For example in grammar `LogicRules` below, lexer token `LPAR` marks the beginning of either a logical expression beginning in rule `compExpr` or an arithmetic expression beginning in `primaryExpr`. ANTLR can't know by default whether input `"(3..."` marks the beginning of a logical expression grouping (`"(3 + 3 == 6)"`) or the beginning of an arithmetic/numeric expression grouping (`"(3 + 3) == 6"`). The syntactic predicate in rule `compExpr` is used to help ANTLR distinguish between these two choices by telling it, in effect, to wait and see.

#### LogicRules.g — Let ANTLR rules distinguish between boolean and numeric expressions

```java
grammar LogicRules;

statement returns [boolean result]
    : logicalExpr {$result = $logicalExpr.result;} EOF
    ;

logicalExpr returns [boolean result]
    @init { $result = true;}
    : lhs=compExpr {$result = $lhs.result;} 
        (AND rhs=compExpr 
            {$result = $result && $rhs.result;}
        )*
    ;

compExpr returns [boolean result]
    @init { $result = true;}
    : (eqExpr) => eqExpr {$result = $eqExpr.result;}
        //^^ Needs a syntactic predicate to differentiate between logical grouping and arithmetic grouping
    | LPAR logicalExpr {$result = $logicalExpr.result;} RPAR
        //^^ Only group logical expressions at this level. 
    ;

eqExpr returns [boolean result]
@init {$result = true;}
    : lhs=arithmeticExpr 
        (EQ rhs=arithmeticExpr 
            {$result = $result && $lhs.result == $rhs.result;}
        )+ 
        //^^ use +: a logical expression of arithmetic expressions
        //          requires a logical operation to produce a boolean value
    ;

arithmeticExpr returns [int result]
    @init {$result = 0;}
    : lhs=primaryExpr {$result += $lhs.result;} 
        (PLUS rhs=primaryExpr 
            {$result += $rhs.result;}
        )* 
    ;

primaryExpr returns [int result]
    @init {$result = 0;}
    :   INT {$result = $INT.int;}
    |   LPAR arithmeticExpr RPAR {$result = $arithmeticExpr.result;}
        //^^ Only group other numeric/arithmetic expressions at this level.
    ;

INT     : ('0'..'9')+;
AND     : '&&';
EQ      : '==';
LPAR    : '(';
RPAR    : ')';
PLUS    : '+'; 
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();};
```

---

Evaluating an expression's result type using code rather than ANTLR rules leads to a grammar like the following. Note that grouping is done only at one level and with no need for a syntactic predicate. The grammar overall is kept relatively simple. Like the previous grammar, this grammar produces an error when it encounters an invalid type conversion.

#### LogicEval.g — Let code distinguish between boolean and numeric expressions

```java
grammar LogicEval;

@parser::members {
    private static boolean toBoolean(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Boolean){
            return (Boolean)obj;
        } else { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert " + obj + " to boolean");
        }
    } 

    private static int toInt(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Integer){
            return (Integer)obj;
        } else { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert " + obj + " to integer");
        }
    } 
}

statement returns [Object result]
    : expr {$result = $expr.result;} EOF
    ;

expr returns [Object result]
    : lhs=compExpr {$result = $lhs.result;} 
        (AND rhs=compExpr 
            {$result = toBoolean($result) && toBoolean($rhs.result);} 
        )*
    ;

compExpr returns [Object result]
    @init {Object lhsResult = null;}
    : lhs=arithmeticExpr {$result = lhsResult = $lhs.result;}
        (EQ rhs=arithmeticExpr
            {$result = toInt(lhsResult) == toInt($rhs.result);} 
        )* 
    ;

arithmeticExpr returns [Object result]
    : lhs=primaryExpr {$result = $lhs.result;}
        (PLUS rhs=primaryExpr
            {$result = toInt($result) + toInt($rhs.result);}
        )*
    ;

primaryExpr returns [Object result]
    :   INT {$result = $INT.int;}
    |   LPAR expr RPAR {$result = $expr.result;}
    ;

INT     : ('0'..'9')+;
AND     : '&&';
EQ      : '==';
LPAR    : '(';
RPAR    : ')';
PLUS    : '+'; 
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();};
```

---

#### LogicTest.java — Test code for the two grammars

```java
public class LogicTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("1 + 2 == 3", Result.True);
        test("1 + 2 == 4", Result.False);
        test("1 + 2 == 3 && 1 + 2 == 4", Result.False);
        test("1 + 2 == 3 && 4 + 5 == 9", Result.True);
        test("(1 + 2) == 3 && (4 + 5 == 9)", Result.True);
        test("1 + 2 == (3 && 4 + 5 == 9)", Result.Failure);
        test("1 && 2", Result.Failure);
        test("1 + 2", Result.Failure);
    }

    private static void test(String rawInput, Result expectedResult){
        Result rulesResult = runRules(rawInput);
        Result evalResult = runEval(rawInput);
        System.out.println("---\n");
        System.out.printf("**Input:** %s%n%n", rawInput);
        System.out.printf("**Expected Result:** %s%n%n", expectedResult);
        System.out.printf("**LogicRules Result:** %s%n%n", rulesResult);
        System.out.printf("**LogicRules Passed?** %s%n%n", (rulesResult == expectedResult));
        System.out.printf("**LogicEval Result:** %s%n%n", evalResult);
        System.out.printf("**LogicEval Passed?** %s%n%n", (evalResult == expectedResult));
    }

    private static Result runRules(String rawInput){
        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(rawInput);
        LogicRulesLexer lexer = new LogicRulesLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        LogicRulesParser parser = new LogicRulesParser(tokens);

        boolean result;
        try {
            result = parser.statement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        if (lexer.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0 || parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0){
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        return result ? Result.True : Result.False;
    }

    private static Result runEval(String rawInput){
        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(rawInput);
        LogicEvalLexer lexer = new LogicEvalLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        LogicEvalParser parser = new LogicEvalParser(tokens);

        Object result;
        try {
            result = parser.statement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        if (lexer.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0 || parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0){
            return Result.Failure;
        }

        if (result instanceof Boolean){
            return ((Boolean)result) ? Result.True : Result.False;
        } else { 
            return Result.Failure; //Produced a valid result, but it wasn't a boolean.
        }
    }

    private static enum Result { 
        True, False, Failure;
    }
}
```

#### Output — All tests pass

---

**Input:** 1 + 2 == 3

**Expected Result:** True

**LogicRules Result:** True

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** True

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 + 2 == 4

**Expected Result:** False

**LogicRules Result:** False

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** False

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 + 2 == 3 && 1 + 2 == 4

**Expected Result:** False

**LogicRules Result:** False

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** False

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 + 2 == 3 && 4 + 5 == 9

**Expected Result:** True

**LogicRules Result:** True

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** True

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** (1 + 2) == 3 && (4 + 5 == 9)

**Expected Result:** True

**LogicRules Result:** True

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** True

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 + 2 == (3 && 4 + 5 == 9)

**Expected Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** Failure

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 && 2

**Expected Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** Failure

**LogicEval Passed?** true

---

**Input:** 1 + 2

**Expected Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Result:** Failure

**LogicRules Passed?** true

**LogicEval Result:** Failure

**LogicEval Passed?** true